# Using Tidyverse to Output a Series of Summary Statistic Tables per User/Participant

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to produce a table of mean scores for each participant in my tibble. The number of observants is much larger than the data given below, but this tibble should be sufficient. I need to produce a table for each unique user_id. I would like the table to have 10 rows, 8 of which are the means of the indicators 1-8 per timepoint, and the other two are domain means per timepoint. The mean of domain 0 is the mean of indicators 1-4, and the mean of domain 1 is the mean of indicators 5-8. I would also like the outputted tables to have four columns, one per timepoint. Thus, each teacher_id's outputted table should be a 10 by 4. I have attempted this with tidyverse and would appreciate help. Also, some users (read several) will not have values at all timepoints.

```
structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), user_id = c("Kim", "Kim", 
"Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", 
"Kim", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
"Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
"Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
"Bob", "Bob", "George", "George", "George", "George", 
"George", "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", 
"George", "George", "George", "George", "George"), indicator = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8"
), Timepoint = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), score = c(3.5, 3.5, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 
3, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 
3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 
3, 3, 2.5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

Attempted tidyverse code:

```
user_tables <- d %>% 
  group_by(user_id,indicator,Timepoint) %>% 
  summarise(Time1 = mean[which(indicator == 1 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 2 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 3 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 4 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 5 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 6 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 7 & Timepoint == 1)], mean[which(indicator == 8 & Timepoint == 1)],
            Time2 = mean[which(indicator == 1 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 2 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 3 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 4 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 5 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 6 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 7 & Timepoint == 2)], mean[which(indicator == 8 & Timepoint == 2)], 
            Time3 = mean[which(indicator == 1 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 2 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 3 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 4 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 5 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 6 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 7 & Timepoint == 3)], mean[which(indicator == 8 & Timepoint == 3)],
            Time4 = mean[which(indicator == 1 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 2 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 3 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 4 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 5 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 6 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 7 & Timepoint == 4)], mean[which(indicator == 8 & Timepoint == 4)]) %>% 
  split(., .$user_id)
```

Ultimately, I would like a table like this per user (where the NAs are the appropriate means) (Note: This one is for Bob - he didn't have scores for time 1 or time 2):

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.625, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, 2.5, 2, 
2.5, 2.5, 3, 2.625, 3, 3, 1.5, 3, 3.75, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.5), .Dim = c(10L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Domain  0", "Ind 1", "Ind 2", "Ind 3", 
"Ind 4", "Domain 1", "Ind  5", "Ind 6", "Ind 7", "Ind 8"), c("Time 1", 
"Time 2", "Time 3", "Time 4")))
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should include the expected output before including your attempted code

Comment: I thought I described it above. Can you say more about expected output?

Comment: replace the NA's in your expected output with the true values using the toy dataset you gave. We would not be able to tell whether we understood the problem or whether the code is working as intended unless we can compare the results

Comment: Okay. I added the values. Hopefully, it's clear now. The math is simple, as the scores are the mean. The  only computation is for the  domain means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding rows, you could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group, user_id, Timepoint, domain = +(indicator>4), indicator) %>%
  summarise(sc=mean(score),.groups ='drop_last') %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Group, user_id, indicator, domain), Timepoint,'Time_', values_from = sc) %>%
  group_nest()%>%
  mutate(data = map(data, 
                ~rbind(c(NA,colMeans(select_if(.x,is.numeric), na.rm = TRUE)),.x)))%>%
  unnest(data)%>%
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(is.na(indicator), 
                            paste0('Domain ', domain), paste0('Ind ', indicator)),
         domain = NULL)

A tibble: 30 x 6
   Group user_id indicator Time_3 Time_4 Time_1
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 Bob     Domain 0    1.62   2.62    NaN
 2     1 Bob     Ind 1       2      3        NA
 3     1 Bob     Ind 2       2.5    3        NA
 4     1 Bob     Ind 3       1.5    1.5      NA
 5     1 Bob     Ind 4       0.5    3        NA
 6     1 Bob     Domain 1    2.5    3.75    NaN
 7     1 Bob     Ind 5       2      4        NA
 8     1 Bob     Ind 6       2.5    4        NA
 9     1 Bob     Ind 7       2.5    3.5      NA
10     1 Bob     Ind 8       3      3.5      NA
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: I added an arrange(Timepoint) right before the pivot_wider to get the timepoints in order. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Same basic idea as in @Onyambu’s answer, but simplified a bit with new dplyr
1.0.0 features that allow `summarise()` to increase the row count:

```r
library(tidyverse)

have %>% 
  mutate(domain = (as.numeric(indicator) - 1) %/% 4) %>% 
  group_by(user_id, Timepoint, domain, indicator) %>% 
  summarise(score = mean(score)) %>% 
  summarise(
    cur_data() %>% add_row(score = mean(score), .before = 1)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(Timepoint) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    values_from = score,
    names_from = Timepoint,
    names_prefix = "Time "
  ) %>% 
  filter(user_id == "Bob")
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'user_id', 'Timepoint', 'domain' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'user_id', 'Timepoint', 'domain' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   user_id, domain [2]
#>    user_id domain indicator `Time 1` `Time 3` `Time 4`
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Bob          0 <NA>            NA     1.62     2.62
#>  2 Bob          0 1               NA     2        3   
#>  3 Bob          0 2               NA     2.5      3   
#>  4 Bob          0 3               NA     1.5      1.5 
#>  5 Bob          0 4               NA     0.5      3   
#>  6 Bob          1 <NA>            NA     2.5      3.75
#>  7 Bob          1 5               NA     2        4   
#>  8 Bob          1 6               NA     2.5      4   
#>  9 Bob          1 7               NA     2.5      3.5 
#> 10 Bob          1 8               NA     3        3.5
```

Data setup:

```r
have <- structure(list(
  Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  user_id = c(
    "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Bob", "Bob",
    "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob",
    "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "George", "George", "George", "George",
    "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", "George",
    "George", "George", "George", "George", "George"
  ),
  indicator = c(
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3",
    "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2",
    "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8"
  ), Timepoint = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4,
    3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4
  ), score = c(
    3.5, 3.5, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5,
    0.5, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5,
    2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.5
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L))

want <- structure(
  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.625, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, 2.5,
    2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 2.625, 3, 3, 1.5, 3, 3.75, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.5),
    .Dim = c(10L, 4L),
    .Dimnames = list(
      c("Domain  0", "Ind 1", "Ind 2", "Ind 3","Ind 4",
        "Domain 1", "Ind  5", "Ind 6", "Ind 7", "Ind 8"),
      c("Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3", "Time 4")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question. How about a `nest` solution? Here, you create a function to summarise, nest the data by `user_id`, then apply the function to each participant.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), user_id = c("Kim", "Kim", 
                                                           "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", "Kim", 
                                                           "Kim", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
                                                           "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
                                                           "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
                                                           "Bob", "Bob", "George", "George", "George", "George", 
                                                           "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", "George", 
                                                           "George", "George", "George", "George", "George"), indicator = c("1", 
                                                                                                                            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
                                                                                                                            "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", 
                                                                                                                            "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8"
                                                           ), Timepoint = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
                                                                            4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
                                                                            3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), score = c(3.5, 3.5, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 
                                                                                                         3, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 
                                                                                                         3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 
                                                                                                         3, 3, 2.5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                              -40L))




output <- structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.625, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, 2.5, 2, 
            2.5, 2.5, 3, 2.625, 3, 3, 1.5, 3, 3.75, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.5), .Dim = c(10L, 
                                                                              4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Domain  0", "Ind 1", "Ind 2", "Ind 3", 
                                                                                                      "Ind 4", "Domain 1", "Ind  5", "Ind 6", "Ind 7", "Ind 8"), c("Time 1", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "Time 2", "Time 3", "Time 4")))



dfnest <- df %>% 
  group_nest(user_id)


my_summarise <- function(.data) {
  .data %>%
    group_by(indicator,Timepoint) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(values_from = mean,names_from = Timepoint,names_prefix = 'Timepoint')
}


map(dfnest$data,my_summarise)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'indicator' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'indicator' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'indicator' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   indicator [8]
#>   indicator Timepoint3 Timepoint4
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 1                2          3  
#> 2 2                2.5        3  
#> 3 3                1.5        1.5
#> 4 4                0.5        3  
#> 5 5                2          4  
#> 6 6                2.5        4  
#> 7 7                2.5        3.5
#> 8 8                3          3.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   indicator [8]
#>   indicator Timepoint3 Timepoint4
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 1                3.5        3  
#> 2 2                2.5        2.5
#> 3 3                2.5        2  
#> 4 4                2          3  
#> 5 5                3.5        3.5
#> 6 6                3.5        3.5
#> 7 7                3          3  
#> 8 8                3          2.5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#> # Groups:   indicator [8]
#>   indicator Timepoint1
#>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 1                3.5
#> 2 2                3.5
#> 3 3                2  
#> 4 4                3  
#> 5 5                3.5
#> 6 6                4  
#> 7 7                3  
#> 8 8                4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>